# Masking a transparent image with another actual image in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have two images, one is a mask that is transparent with some edges / borders and the other is the actual image. I want to merge both of them.

[image]                   [image]

I have used the following code to mask and combine the image:

```
 - (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    // create a bitmap graphics context the size of the image
    CGFloat dim = MIN(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(dim, dim);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, .0);
    UIBezierPath *bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:(CGRect){ CGPointZero, size }];
    [bezierPath fill];
    [bezierPath addClip];
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake((dim - image.size.width) * 0.5, (dim - image.size.height) * 0.5);
    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){ offset, image.size }];
    UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return ret;
}
```

The result:

[image]

**In the result image, the border of the image used as a mask is missing**. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You never draw maskImage to your context or use maskImage in any way in your method...

Comment: is there any way to achieve. i don't know how to do. i have just taken the code from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a masking category for ios (well it is basically cross platform because CoreImage is on both platforms anyway:

[github project](https://github.com/Daij-Djan/DDEnhancedJSBridge/tree/master/DDEnhancedJSBridge/__DEMO_CODE_AND_RESOURCES__)

the core functionality boils down to this (for your example)

```
UIImage *person = ...
UIImage *circle = ...
UIImage *result = [person imageMaskedWith:circle];

UIImageView *redbox = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:result];
redbox.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //this can be a gradient!
```

---

the main part of the code from the category:

```
CGImageRef imageReference = image.CGImage;
CGImageRef maskReference = mask.CGImage;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(imageReference), CGImageGetHeight(imageReference));

// draw with Core Graphics
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, 0.0, rect.size.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextClipToMask(bitmap, rect, maskReference);
CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, rect, imageReference);

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```